# Lua is it possible to load all local variables into a table, and/or dynamically create a local variable?

Tags: lua, local

I have actually been wondering about this question for a long time, and I can recall reading something somewhere on the internet about loading all local variables into a table, but I could never find it again.
What I am wondering is if there is basically any way to dynamically create a local variable, similar to how you can dynamically create a global variable.
In Lua you can create dynamic global variables simply by saying:

```
local my_env = getfenv(1);
for i = 1, 10 do
    my_env["OMG_DYNAMIC_GLOBAL_VARIABLE_"..i] = i * i;
end
```

But I have always wondered if there is a way to essentially do the same or a similar thing for local variables. Something like

```
for i = 1, 10 do
    local["OMG_DYNAMIC_LOCAL_VARIABLE_"..i] = i * i;
end
```

would kind of be pseudo code for what I am trying to do.
As a second part to my question, I am wondering if there is any way to possibly iterate through every local variable in the current scope? I guess pseudo code for what I am trying to do would look something like:

```
local a = 123;
local b = 321;
LocalVars = {(local)}; --the table with the local variables in it.
for i,v in pairs(LocalVars) do print(i, v); end
```

I would appreciate any help regarding either part of my question.
Thanks

Comment: Its possible to check every local thus putting them into table, check debug.getlocal example: https://www.lua.org/pil/23.1.1.html But dont use this to solve problems, this is for debug purposes (performance issues)

Comment: What problem are really trying to solve? If you could create local variables dynamically, how would your use this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the table with the local variables in it

There is no table with local variables. Local variables do not exist in compiled Lua. There are simply locations on the Lua stack and/or upvalues. Even the names of local variables are lost during the compilation process.

Local variables are always static constructs of the Lua source code. They never exist within a table. If you need a non-static construct, use a table. That's what tables are for. That's (part of) why Lua globals are in a table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the advantage of what you proposed over a regular local table except for syntactic sugar.

```
local locals = {}
locals.a = 123
locals.b = 321
for i,v in pairs(locals) do
   print(i, v)
end
```

---

The syntax you proposed does not make the program clearer or easier to read in any way.  In fact it even creates new problems.  Does the following print `c` as well or does it not because it is in a nested local scope?

```
for i,v in pairs(LocalVars) do
   local c = 1729
   print(i, v)
end
```